# Can the acceleration of the object thrown by man exceed the acceleration of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, escape-velocity

Can the acceleration of an object thrown by man exceed the acceleration of gravity? I don't think so. Otherwise, how could the object fall back to the ground?

Comment: An object falls back to Earth if the velocity when it leaves your hand is less than the escape velocity. Are you asking if it's possible to throw something so it leaves your hand at a velocity greater than escape velocity? If so, note that the escape velocity is a bit over 11 km/sec.

Comment: @JohnRennie How fast can a human hand throw a ball?

Comment: [The fastest baseball pitch is about 0.05 km/sec](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/how-aroldis-chapman-threw-the-fastest-pitch-ever_b_57c38390e4b06384eb4066ef), and that's several orders of magnitude lower than the escape velocity.

Comment: @JohnRennie So why does the object move up when it leaves the hand?

Comment: Because acceleration is the rate of change of velocity. The gravitational acceleration at the Earth's surface is $-9.8m/s^2$ (the minus sign means the acceleration is downwards). So if I throw an object up with a velocity of $+98m/s^2$ (positive means upwards) every second the Earth's gravity reduces the speed by $9.8m/s$. So after moving upwards for 10 seconds the upwards velocity decreases to zero and the object starts falling back.

Answer (score 1):

To accelerate an object, you have to continuously apply force on it. When you throw an object, you only give it an impulse ie impart some velocity to it.

Comment: So why does the object move up when it leaves the hand?

Comment: Because you have given the object **upward** velocity. The object moves in the direction of its velocity not acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration is a force dependent quantity so unless a force acts on a body it does not accelerate. So as soon as you throw a ball the force from your hands acting on the ball ceases to exist and the only force left is gravity which continues to convert this the kinetic energy gained so into the potential energy of the system. But you can always use a rope and a pulley to pull things(though you might have not intended to do this).

So does it mean that the acceleration of your hands is greater than $g$ in magnitude? The answer is No! (It needs not to be) it only means that the upward acceleration provided by your hand was enough to provide substantial change in momentum. You cannot compare the magnitudes of acceleration in both the case without making quantitative analysis (i.e., to say the acceleration can be even less than $g$ in magnitude (or can be greater than too!).

So it would be better to compare forces than accelerations as then you can directly say that the force from your hands while throwing the balls was more than that of weight of the ball.

Comment: You mean acceleration was enough at first, but not enough later.

Comment: @EbinZheng No it means that initially the upward acceleration was enough to provide substantial change in momentum and it would be better to compare forces than accelerations as then you can directly say that the force from your hands while throwing was more than that of weight of the ball.

Comment: @Enbinzheng I have modified my answer as per your comment.

Comment: The force of your hand can be greater than the weight of the ball, but the acceleration will not be greater than the acceleration of gravity?

Comment: @enbinzheng yes! It's not necessary for the acceleration to be greater than $g$ rather it could have any possible value.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the acceleration of the object thrown by man exceed the acceleration of gravity?

Before the release of the throw, yes. After the release, no.

You can easily test this with the accelerometer in a cell phone, although it could get expensive if you are not careful.

Comment: So why is there escape speed?

Comment: Speed and acceleration have nothing to do with each other (mathematically they are orthogonal). Your question was about acceleration, not speed. Don’t downvote my answer if you asked about acceleration when you wanted to know about speed.